# NetSuite NSPOS 2020.1.20 constantly fails staging attempts

Tags: netsuite

I have been trying to stage a register into NetSuite's NSPOS 2020.1.20 for sandbox testing. Every attempt has failed so far; after several packages install, one will fail after "Sending refresh to server using Refresh" for up to an hour.  I have tried with the Defender firewall up, down, and ACLs in place to allow the FQDN of the retailanywhere.com & netsuite servers through our company's main firewall.  Has anyone else run into this?  NetSuite's support team is trying to be helpful, but they don't have any problems staging with the links I send them.  I have sent them logs, specs, you name it, and they can't figure out what's wrong.

Currently I'm defragging the hard drive to see if that will help.  I got a SSD to succeed once, and then it's failed every time since.  The logs say that something is blocking the endpoint on the host machine, but with Defender completely turned off I don't know what that could be.  There is not other anti-malware on the PC.